# How to apply style class for t:commandSortHeader in JSF?

Tags: java, css, jsf, tomahawk

In my application i am using `t:commandSortHeader` for sorting purpose, is it possible to change the default arrow thats is shown to some other image using styleClass attributes. If possible how to do that. Kindly help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

not sure but did you try like this

```
 <t:commandSortHeader arrow="false" ... >
 <f:facet name="ascending">  
 <t:graphicImage url="asc.png" />  
</facet> 
 <f:facet name="descending">
 <t:graphicImage url="desc.png"/> 
 </facet>
```

Comment: This is great one! May I know how did you get the `facet` reference? Beside ascending and descending, is there any other facet available?